# Add stock filter in layered navigation in Magento2

Tags: filter, custom-controls, magento2, layered-navigation

I need to add stock filter in layered navigation, so the user can filter the in stock and out stock products.

I have tried to [implement this](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/122972/magento2-product-collection-filter-out-of-stock-products) but didn't get any results.

How can I do this?